# Android ionic cordova send MMS

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, sms, mms

I try to make an mobile app with ionic, and I send SMS without problems, however I don't know how to send MMS.

I know this [plugin](https://github.com/jondspa/cordova-sms-plugin)
but I don't know how to import it in ionic ?

Is there another solution ? Or could you help me to import this plugin please ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in that link, firstly you will use the command

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/jondspa/cordova-sms-plugin.git
```

then as a one option create a .js file and include the mentioned code, and then include that .js to your .ts file by ScriptLoaderService plugin.

After that you will do something like this:

```
constructor(public script: ScriptLoaderService){};

this.script.load('assets/.../example.js').then(() => {}); //will load your .js
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
When I try that (after launch the commande  ionic cordova plugin add) :
import { SMS } from 'cordova-sms-plugin';
Ionic said me that cordova-sms-plugin is unfound